# why don't ls -lrt `find .` and find . -exec ls -lrt {} \+ produce the same output?

Tags: bash, find, ls

I'm trying to sort files by date, including those that reside in subdirectories.  I got it to work by using:

```
find . -exec ls -lrt {} \+
```

which I found somewhere on StackOverflow.  My initial try was to use:

```
ls -lrt `find .`
```

but it doesn't work.  It sorts the contents of each directory by date, rather than all of them together.

Why do these produce different output?

Answer (score 3):

Use `d` option of `ls`.

```
ls -lrtd `find .`
```